# Dolphin runs as root in KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 22.04.  I followed a different StackOverflow answer to launch Dolphin as root using:

```
sudo SUDO_USER= dolphin
```

At this point, I don't want to run dolphin as root again.

If I launch dolphin from the application launcher, it runs as my current user, as before.  However, if I use Meta+E or if I use Alt-F2/Alt-Space to launch from Krunner, Dolphin always runs as root.  How can I fix this and have Krunner launch Dolphin as the current user?

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed now.  I rebooted and it reverted back to normal.